# SQL data column merge together if value exists already

Tags: sql, sql-server

[SQL Server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McV7E.jpg)

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViUJx.jpg)

```
SELECT [Order Number]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Return ID]
      ,[Createddateandtime]
      ,[Item Quantity]
FROM [PowerBIXPO].[dbo].[ReturnHeader]
```

I have just started using SQL I need to merge both columns together if the value already exists. I am using SSIS to import return customer data to a SQL Server table which works fine but because the source CSV file contains the data on a separate column and is inserting the data on a new line instead of merging the data together but unable to do this.

If the column `Return ID` and `Item Quantity` already exist, it needs to merge the data and total the quantities can you somebody provide a solution to this please.

I am using SSIS integration services to merge the data before inserting it into the SQL Server table.

Comment: 1) avoid the use of images. 2) provide sample data and expected results given the sample data. 3) Define the business rules for combining the data.  As it stands I don't know if you just need to add a "Distinct" after select, or if you want to group by after your where clause all the columns except those you aggregrate (Sum/average/count) and `sum(Item Quantity)`  when you say "merge" you mean combine the rows and sum the item quantities?

Comment: Also, if we are combining the rows, what do you want to have happen if the order number, date, name, email adn created date and time are different?   Which shoudl we pick and why?   Keep in mind we know nothing about your system and data other than what you tell us.  We want to help you but there's a minimal amount of information we need to help you.

Comment: Also your screenshot you use a top without an order by.  Maybe that's just to get sample data which is fine; but if it's intended to be a final query, top without an order by will result in bad behavior as the system will not know what "Top" records to provide. So results could vary over time as data in the system changes.

Comment: Maybe the business rules are group by all the columns except item quantity? and sum item quantity? this would have the effect of combining the rows and suming the item quantities.   I'd encourage laying out the data for 2-3 orders with a return on each and show expectations.  You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to help mockup the data.  a copy and paste from a data window is usually enough!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered NOT polluting your data by importing it into the final table, but to import it into a staging table and then process it from there - then you can remove duplicates in this table. Using staging tables is standard data loading practice since - not sure. 30 years at least. You can then remove duplicates and do a classical MERGE statement that can be used to either insert or update.